# Naming Sections in Grouped UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a grouped table view with two sections.. I have an NSArray which pulls in 5 section titles from a database, I want the first section in the uitableview to have four rows, whose titles are set to the first four elements in the NSArray and the second section to contain a whose title is set to the last element in the array, how is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Everything depends on what you return from your data source's `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` and `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` methods. Sounds like you want 2 sections, with 4 rows in the first and 1 in the second — you can do this by checking `indexPath.section` in `numberOfRowsInSection:` and returning the appropriate value. Then in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, you can use `indexPath.section+indexPath.row` to get the overall row number.